# High CPU Usage From Repeating Dates/Calendar

Tags: datetime

My client just discovered that when he publishes 4-6 events that repeat throughout the year/weekly the website becomes really slow to the point of which the server goes down. He even received an email from the hosting company saying that there was a high percent of CPU usage. They lowered his CPU limit from 20% to 10%. In the email it showed that the public_html was using more than 90%.

How can we fix this?

Comment: There is not enough information. What are the events? Just a custom content type or supplied by a specific module? If they are from a module, have you entered an issue in the module's issue queue. Are there any custom modules on the site?

Comment: It is just using the Date API and Calendar module. A content type called event which uses the Date API and Date Repeat API/Field.

Comment: What have you done to debug this yourself? Have you taken a look at the SQL query that is run on the calendar view?

Comment: Also details about the hosting itself might help as well - it sounds as if it is a shared host, meaning the available resources are pretty low.

Comment: Use of a tool like New Relic to aggregate performance data would be optimal. I'd also suggest moving off of shared hosting to either a service that specializes in Drupal hosting or a VPS with guaranteed resources.